# C Serial Communication. WriteFile succeeds but my device only processes 1st character

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, writefile

I'm trying to implement serial communication with a hardware device that plugs into the USB port on my PC. Im writing the communication code in C using Visual Studio 2015.

I'm using a USB sniffer to help see what data is being sent to and from the device. I'm also using the TeraTerm serial app for testing.

I'm connecting OK to the device with my C-code . However I'm having a problem writing data to the device. I can write a single character e.g a "\r" and the device will respond appropriately by sending "command not found" back. I can see this using the USB sniffer.

However if I try and send "ver\r" then as soon as the device receives the first character, "v", it responds with "command not found". If use TeraTerm and type "ver\r" I get a version number sent back (I don't get "command not found" as soon as I type "v"). Note I can see from the USB sniffer program that 4 bytes "ver\r" are being sent out to the device. I've also checked this using the "number of bytes" value returned from the WriteFile command.

So for some reason the device acts on the 1st character received. Everything works perfectly using the TeraTerm app so I can only think I've done something wrong in the software, maybe something really obvious. However I've spent ages on this and everything looks OK. I've kept things simple and I've some experience on serial communication for another device which worked almost 1st time. So I've no idea why the device is acting on the 1st character received?

```
int count = 0;
char vPortName[20];

sprintf((char*)vPortName, "%s%s", "\\\\.\\", comPort);

g_thePort = CreateFileA(vPortName,
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                        0, 
                        NULL, 
                        OPEN_EXISTING, 
                        0,
                        NULL);



DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
g_result = OK;

dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
if (!GetCommState(g_thePort, &dcbSerialParams))
    g_result = ERR_GETCOMMSTATE;

if (g_result == OK)
{
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
}

if (g_result == OK)
{
    if (!SetCommState(g_thePort, &dcbSerialParams))
        g_result = ERR_SETCOMMSTATE;
}

if (g_result == OK)
{
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };

    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(g_thePort, &timeouts))
        g_result = ERR_SETTIMEOUTS;
}

if(g_result == OK)
{
        char command[4] = {"v", "e", "r", "\r"};
    DWORD numbytes = 0;

    PurgeComm(g_thePort, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);

    g_count = strlen(command);

    WriteFile(g_thePort, command, g_count, &numbytes, NULL)
 }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Visual Studio but with gcc that won't even compile. `command` is not being initialised the way you think it is. You need to use single quotes for chars not double quotes. Also, `command` needs to be NUL terminated. Try `char command[] = "ver\r";`

Comment: Thanks yes points noted. Changing the format of "command" was something I had already played about with. Ive made the change as you suggest with no change to the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The initialized array

```
 char command[4] = {"v", "e", "r", "\r"};
```

should have produced at least a warning. You are not assigning characters to `command`'s elements. Change it to

```
 char command[4] = {'v', 'e', 'r', '\r'};
```

or even better

```
char command[] = "ver\r";
```

In the second case you need to call `strlen` to obtain the number of characters. `command` will hold one character more, `'\0'`.

BTW, calling `strlen()` on a character array *without* that end-of-string marker evokes undefined behavior. What you should have written is

```
g_count = sizeof command;
```

Comment: Thanks points noted re format of "command". Id already tried various formats and your suggestion has not changed what is happening. For some reason the device only responds to the 1st character being sent and does not wait for the "\r" even though it works ok on TeraTerm. Note Ive tried experimenting with the end of command character ie "\n", "\r" or "\r\n" but not making any progress.

Comment: What happens if you reduce `command` to `"v"`? And which values are returned by `WriteFile()` and in `numBytes`? --- Which bytes does your USB sniffer show as transfered? --- What happens if your first character is `'\r'` like in `"\rver\r"`?

Comment: Oh, and how is the device communicating actually? Is there a hardware USB-serial converter before a microcontroller or similar receives the bytes? If so, are the communication parameters (baudrate, number of data bits, parity) correct?

Comment: Yes. These are correct because same as in Tera Term

Comment: 5 to 6 questions asked, 1 answered, 4 to 5 still open. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OK I've finally got it working. Sending the entire string (using WriteFile) does not work as I've explained. However sending each character one at a time (using WriteFile) with a 1 second delay between each one did work! I will try with a shorter delay than 1 second but whatever, I assume therefore the device is just extremely slow to process the data being sent to it?